# Archiving Team Foundation Server Projects

Tags: tfs

We're starting to user Team Foundation Server and my boss would like some way to "archive" projects. Meaning after they are completed, remove them from an "active" state so that only "active" projects are visible.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

I've thought of 2 options.

1) Create 2 base projects. 1 for active projects and 1 for achived projects

2) Remove all users from the archived projects.

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would personally recommend waiting for TFS 2010 when more functionality will be introduced that will assist you in the ability to "archive" Team Projects.

In TFS 2010 you will hopefully be able to move a team project to a new Team Project Collection.  Actually you do this by duplicating your "active" project collection and then deleting all the team projects from it apart from the one that you want archived.  In this active project collection, delete the archived project that you have a copy of in the duplicated project collection.  This archived team project will then live in it's own project collection which means it has it's own database etc which can be easily backed up / archived etc.

The archived team project project collection can then be left as it is as it doesn't slow down the server any if not being used - or it could even be detached from the TFS Application instance so that it doesn't show up at all and re-attached at any time.

An advantage of using project collections in TFS 2010 is that full Version Control and Work Item Tracking history will be maintained.

Answer (score 2):

I would use it just as you normally do, but when you are done with the project then you remove it from the visible list.  (In Visual Studio you can right click on a project in the team explorer and say remove.)

If you are worried about changes after the project is done, then remove the users from the contributors list.  If you really want to boot the users out (so they cannot even see it) then you can deny them rights to the project.

This way you don't have to see it, but you can keep all your projects on the base level.

I would NOT recommend having just 2 base project for active and in-active.  A TFS project should not be based on a state.

Answer (score 1):

We created an "Archive" team project and we regularly move unused source code to that team project.  It has worked out well for us, the history is preserved so we can always reference the archive project for old code or information on past changes.  We also limit access such that developers have read access but only TFS administrators have write access.  I haven't checked to see how these moves impact the association of check-ins with work items - mostly because everything we archived was checked in before we moved to TFS.

As for the one active team project, I was led to believe by knowledge experts and online documentation that this wasn't the best way to organize team projects.  I think ideally you group projects/solutions together into a single team project if they are related (i.e. by line of business or dependencies).

I'm sure you've already done your research, but there is plenty of documentation out there that might assist (especially if your team maintains a single application or a handful of applications).  I would suggest starting with [patterns & practices: Team Development with TFS](http://www.codeplex.com/TFSGuide).

Comment: Link is broken!